# Finding a transformation matrix in $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

> Let $B, C$ be some ordered basis (given as sequences) of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Given that $T: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is a linear transformation which satisfies: 
>  $$[T]^{C}_{C} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$ and $$[T \circ T]^{B}_{C} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$ 
>  Find the matrices $[T]^{B}_{C}$ $\space$ and $\space$ $[Id _ {\mathbb{R}^{2}}]^{B} _ {C}$.

---

Well I know that $[T]^{B}_{C} = [T]^{C} _ {C} \space [Id _ {\mathbb{R}^{2}}]^{B} _ {C}$, 
 however I struggle to see what should be the next step, since if I try to figure the $Id$ matrix above, I just get to the starting point again.

Hope to find some ideas.

Comment: I'll give you a hint: $[T\circ T]^B_C = [T]^B_C [T]^C_C$ if I have the same notation as you do (btw you should precise it to avoid confusion). Then use $[T^{-1}]^C_C = \left([T]_C^C\right)^{-1}$

Comment: I can see how to solve it assuming the last equation you specified, however I am trying to understand why it is true

Comment: The matrix representation is an algebra morphism, which means multiplication is preserved, hence the inverse commutes with the matrix rpz